# test expression--usage message

Tags: linux

I am looking for a test expression with a usage message. When I enter in command line a file such as ./file I need the script to stop and echo error. When I enter ./file test I need the file to run and enter file. I am having a hard time using test expression message. So far I have this and it sort of does what I want it to but I need to check and make sure ./file test is actually input to enter file. if it's not input at command properly it should spit an error and exit.

```
   if [$# -eq 0 ]
      then
           echo"error"
      exit 1
   fi
```

Answer (score 5):

`[` is a command; `[$#` is not. You need to separate a command from its arguments:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "error"   # Here, too
    exit 1
fi
```

Incidentally, you can replace that whole block with a special parameter expansion:

```
: ${1?error}
```

If the first positional parameter isn't set (i.e., there are no positional parameters), print the message following the ? and exit.

Comment: Im lost sorry for my ignorance I don't understand